# Неправильно работает событие onclick

Tags: javascript, аудио, webrtc

Добрый день, при нажатии на кнопку `onclick='audioRecorder.open(this)` спрашивает разрешение на микрофон и при нажатии на разрешить запись сразу стартует, при этом когда нажимаешь виднеется мельком кнопка (в виде rec) как сделать чтобы при нажатии спрашивало разрешение и после нажатия на другую кнопку допустим (rec) запись уже стартовала

```js
var audioRecorder = {};
audioRecorder.secondsToTime = function(v, b) {
  var r, h = 0,
    m = 0,
    s = 0;
  if (v >= 3600) {
    h = Math.floor(v / 3600 % 24);
  }
  if (v >= 60) {
    m = Math.floor(v / 60 % 60);
  }
  s = Math.floor(v % 60);
  if (s < 10) {
    s = '0' + s;
  }
  if (h > 0 && m < 10) {
    m = '0' + m;
  }
  r = m + ':' + s;
  if (b || h > 0) {
    r = h + ':' + r;
  }
  return r;
};
audioRecorder.time = function(o, e) {
  var parent = $(o).parents('.audioRecorder');
  var slider = parent.find('.progressWrapper');
  var sliderW = slider.width();
  var duration = audioRecorder.player.duration;
  var x = e.clientX - slider[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var ct = (x * duration) / sliderW;
  audioRecorder.player.currentTime = ct;
};
audioRecorder.start = function(el) {
  var audioRecorderElem = $(el).parents('.audioRecorder');
  var status = audioRecorderElem.attr('status');
  if (status == 'record') {
    audioRecorder.stop(el);
  } else if (status == 'stop') {
    audioRecorder.play(el);
  } else if (status == 'pause') {
    audioRecorder.play(el);
  } else if (status == 'play') {
    audioRecorder.pause(el);
  } else {
    audioRecorder.record(el);
  }
};
audioRecorder.record = function(el) {
  var audioRecorderElem = $(el).parents('.audioRecorder');
  try {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    audioRecorder.context = new AudioContext;
  } catch (e) {
    alert('Ваш браузер не поддерживает веб аудио!');
    return false;
  }
  navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: 1
  }, function(stream) {
    audioRecorder.localStream = stream;
    var input = audioRecorder.context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    audioRecorder.recorder = new Recorder(input);
    audioRecorder.recorder.record();
    audioRecorder.startRecordTime(el);
    audioRecorderElem.attr({
      'status': 'record'
    });
  }, function(err) {});
};
audioRecorder.stop = function(el) {
  var audioRecorderElem = $(el).parents('.audioRecorder');
  audioRecorderElem.attr({
    'status': 'stop'
  });
  audioRecorder.recorder.stop();
  audioRecorder.stopRecordTime(el);
  audioRecorder.recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
    audioRecorder.blob = blob;
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    audioRecorder.player = audioRecorderElem.find('audio')[0];
    audioRecorder.player.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
      var duration = audioRecorder.player.duration;
      var current = audioRecorder.player.currentTime;
      var r = (current * 100) / duration;
      $('.audioRecorder .progressBar').css({
        'width': r + '%'
      });
      time = audioRecorder.secondsToTime(current);
      $('.audioRecorder .duration').text(time);
      if (duration == current) {
        $('.audioRecorder').attr({
          'status': 'stop'
        });
      }
    });
    audioRecorder.player.src = url;
    audioRecorder.recorder.clear();
    audioRecorder.removeMicrophone();
  });
};
audioRecorder.play = function(el) {
  var audioRecorderElem = $(el).parents('.audioRecorder');
  audioRecorder.player.play();
  audioRecorderElem.attr({
    'status': 'play'
  });
};
audioRecorder.pause = function(el) {
  var audioRecorderElem = $(el).parents('.audioRecorder');
  audioRecorder.player.pause();
  audioRecorderElem.attr({
    'status': 'pause'
  });
};
audioRecorder.startRecordTime = function(el) {
  var audioRecorderElem = $(el).parents('.audioRecorder');
  var durElem = audioRecorderElem.find('.duration');
  var ft = new Date().getTime();
  audioRecorder.idInt = setInterval(function() {
    var current = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - ft) / 1000);
    if (current >= 15) {
      audioRecorder.stop(el);
      audioRecorder.stopRecordTime();
    }
    var time = audioRecorder.secondsToTime(current);
    durElem.text(time);
  }, 500);

};
audioRecorder.stopRecordTime = function(el) {
  clearInterval(audioRecorder.idInt);
};
audioRecorder.removeMicrophone = function() {
  try {
    audioRecorder.localStream.getTracks()[0].stop();
  } catch (e) {}
};
audioRecorder.reset = function(el) {
  var audioRecorderElem = $(el).parents('.audioRecorder');
  audioRecorder.removeMicrophone();
  audioRecorder.stopRecordTime();
  audioRecorderElem.removeAttr('status');
  if (audioRecorder.player) {
    audioRecorder.player.currentTime = 0;
    audioRecorder.player.src = '';
  }
  audioRecorderElem.find('.progressBar').css({
    'width': '0%'
  });
  audioRecorder.hide(el);
  try {
    audioRecorder.recorder.clear();
  } catch (e) {}
};
audioRecorder.open = function(el) {
  var audioRecorderElem = $(el).parents('.audioRecorder');
  audioRecorderElem.find('.controlPanelWrapper').show(400, function() {
    audioRecorder.record(el);
  });
};
audioRecorder.hide = function(el) {
  var audioRecorderElem = $(el).parents('.audioRecorder');
  audioRecorderElem.find('.controlPanelWrapper').hide(400, function() {

  });
};
audioRecorder.send = function(el) {
  var post_id = $(el).attr('post-id');
  var user_id = $(el).attr('user-id');
  var page_id = $(el).attr('page-id');
  var audioRecorderElem = $(el).parents('.audioRecorder');
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    var base64 = reader.result;


    //здесь посылаешь base64 на сервер

    $.post("file.php", {
      "audio": base64
    }, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log('stop');
      var text = '[audio records/' + data + '.wav]';
      ///alert(text);
      var esc = $.Event("keyup", {
        keyCode: 13
      });
      esc.keyCode = 13;
      esc.shiftKey = 0;

      Wo_RegisterCommentClick(text, post_id, user_id, page_id);
    });

  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(audioRecorder.blob);
};


var audioPlayer = {};
audioPlayer.play = function(el) {
  var playerParent = $(el).parents('.audioPlayer');
  var player = playerParent.find('audio');
  var progressWrapper = playerParent.find('.progressWrapper');
  var seekBar = playerParent.find('.seekBar');
  var progressBar = playerParent.find('.progressBar');
  var currentElem = playerParent.find('.current');
  var durationElem = playerParent.find('.duration');
  if (!el.h1) {
    player[0].addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
      var duration = player[0].duration;
      var w = progressWrapper.css('width');
      var current = player[0].currentTime;
      var r = (current * 100) / duration;
      progressBar.css({
        'width': r + '%'
      });
      if (duration) {
        var b = false;
        if ((duration / 3600) >= 1) {
          b = true;
        }
        var time = audioPlayer.secondsToTime(current, b);
        currentElem.html(time);
        durationElem.html(audioPlayer.secondsToTime(duration, b));
      }
      if (duration == current) {
        playerParent.attr({
          'status': 'pause'
        });
      }
    });
    el.h1 = 1;
    player[0].src = playerParent.attr('src');
    player[0].volume = 0.7;
  }
  if (player[0].paused) {
    player[0].play();
    playerParent.attr({
      'status': 'play'
    });
  } else {
    player[0].pause();
    playerParent.attr({
      'status': 'pause'
    });
  }
};
audioPlayer.stop = function(el) {
  var playerParent = $(el).parents('.audioPlayer');
  var player = playerParent.find('audio');
  player[0].pause();
  player[0].currentTime = 0;
  playerParent.attr({
    'status': 'stop'
  });
};
audioPlayer.time = function(el, e) {
  var playerParent = $(el).parents('.audioPlayer');
  var player = playerParent.find('audio');
  var slider = playerParent.find('.progressWrapper');
  var sliderW = slider.width();
  var duration = player[0].duration;
  var x = e.clientX - slider[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var ct = (x * duration) / sliderW;
  player[0].currentTime = ct;
};
audioPlayer.volume = function(el, e) {
  var playerParent = $(el).parents('.audioPlayer');
  var player = playerParent.find('audio');
  var slider = playerParent.find('.volumeWrapper');
  var volumeBar = playerParent.find('.volumeBar');
  var sliderW = slider.width();
  var x = e.clientX - slider[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var r = (x * 100) / sliderW;
  var v = Math.floor(r);
  player[0].volume = (v / 100);
  volumeBar.css({
    'width': r + '%'
  });
};
audioPlayer.secondsToTime = function(v, b) {
  var r, h = 0,
    m = 0,
    s = 0;
  if (v >= 3600) {
    h = Math.floor(v / 3600 % 24);
  }
  if (v >= 60) {
    m = Math.floor(v / 60 % 60);
  }
  s = Math.floor(v % 60);
  if (s < 10) {
    s = '0' + s;
  }
  if (h > 0 && m < 10) {
    m = '0' + m;
  }
  r = m + ':' + s;
  if (b || h > 0) {
    r = h + ':' + r;
  }
  return r;
};
/***/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='audioRecorder' status=''>
  <i style="font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #9d9d9d;" class="material-icons" onclick='audioRecorder.open(this);'>mic</i>
  <audio></audio>
  <div class='controlPanelWrapper'>
    <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='controlPanel'>
      <tr>
        <td class='mainbtnContainer'>
          <div class='mainbtn' onclick='audioRecorder.start(this);'></div>
        </td>
        <td class='progressContainer'>
          <div class='progressBlock'>
            <div class='progressWrapper' onclick='audioRecorder.time(this,event);'>
              <div class='progressBar'></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class='durationContainer'>
          <div class='duration'>0:00</div>
        </td>
        <td class='resetContainer' onclick='audioRecorder.reset(this);'>
          <div class='reset'></div>
        </td>
        <td class='sendContainer' onclick='audioRecorder.send(this);' post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" user-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['publisher']['user_id']; ?>" page-id="<?php echo (!empty($wo['story']['publisher']['page_id'])) ? $wo['story']['publisher']['page_id'] : '0'; ?>">
          <div class='send'></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Вы какую то библиотеку `js` забыли дать в вопросе или я что то не так понял?